# Inserting js variable into a form variable

Tags: javascript, forms, parsing, variables, radio-button

I am trying to pass js variable through a hidden form to a php script. No problem in passing it throught to php, however I can't the variable into the form.

```
function calculate() {    
            var radio1 = document.forms["calcForm"].v1;
            var radio2 = document.forms["calcForm"].v2;

            var getf1 = getSelectedRadio(radio1);
            var getf2 = getSelectedRadio(radio2);

            var f1 = radio1[getf1].value;
            var f2 = radio2[getf2].value;

            var resultat = document.getElementById("resultat");
            var total = (parseInt(f1) + parseInt(f2)).toFixed(0);
            resultat.value = total;//used to show value in another input-field
            }

document.contactForm.formTotal.value = total;
```

It's the last line causing me problems, since it would not accept total. The function calculate works perfectly - so does everything else when I replace total with a more simple variable like var x= 10;

Somehow I would like to find a way to set document.contactForm.formTotal.value to the value of total.

The reason must be that it cannot retract some of the values from the function - however my knowledge about js is simply to limited to come up with a solution.

Comment: Put the last line inside the function, or have the function return the results and assign it directly

Comment: Have a look at the scope of total. It's a local variable only valid inside the function calculate.

Comment: I'm embarrassed but very thankfull.
You're absolutely correct, @thebreiflabb. As are the rest of you, of course.
If you put it in an answer I'll accept it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Total is defined as a local variable inside the function, and as such cannot be used in assignments outside the function.

You can either move the assignment inside the function, or have the function return the value.

Answer (score 0):

The variable `total` is out of the function scope. You can declare it in the function but a better way would be for the function to return a value, e.g:

```
function calculate() {    
        var radio1 = document.forms["calcForm"].v1;
        var radio2 = document.forms["calcForm"].v2;

        var getf1 = getSelectedRadio(radio1);
        var getf2 = getSelectedRadio(radio2);

        var f1 = radio1[getf1].value;
        var f2 = radio2[getf2].value;

        var resultat = document.getElementById("resultat");
        var total = (parseInt(f1) + parseInt(f2)).toFixed(0);
        return resultat.value;//used to show value in another input-field
        }

var total = calculate()
```